# Match two columns with similar data

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I have two columns that I wold like to match and compare but using the usually (example) Column A1 = Column B1 wont work.

In both Column A and B, there are full names but not in the same order. For example:

Column A will Show **John Smith** but Column B shows **Smith, John** or possible **Smith, R John**.

Is there anyway to compare these two columns that share similar data but in different order? Currently, I am receiving FALSE for about 18,000 records and it will take to long to manually go through them.

Comment: Microsoft has Fuzzy Lookup addon.

Comment: @Scott Craner, is the add-on the only option? I currently do not have the add-on.

Comment: No, you can write your own code that does the same.  But there is no easy formula that will get you there.

Comment: Awesome information. Just downloaded the fuzzy lookup add-on. Thank you for the help Scott. I can select you as answer if you want to post it below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to invest about an hour of coding, you could write a VBA function that compares two strings by first splitting them into arrays containing individual words (eliminating commas), then sorting arrays alphabetically, and finally comparing arrays token by token. Then it's a simple matter of referencing your new function in the cell.